# Entity Framework Plus - is it possible to share entities between different queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I am evaluating EntityFramework Plus for EF6 .NET framework 4.7.2 (not Core).

During preliminary investigation I found that by default the cache keys are based on the SQL query, not the types of entities in the result set.

My question is, are the entities in the cache shared in some fashion?

For example if my first EF query was:

```
var employees = myContext.LookupData.Where(x=>x.Id < 100).FromCache()
```

And my second EF query, executed say 10 minutes **after the first myContext was Dispose()d** , was:

```
var employees = myContext.LookupData.Where(x=>x.Id < 50).FromCache()
```

We can see that the result set for the second query is going to contain records from the first query.

Would Entity Framework Plus check to see if the entities EF is about to materialize in memory already exist in the cache from the first query, or in some shared entity cache?

If not, what is best practice to cache never-changing, or infrequently changed, entities with EF Plus, to be shared between queries?

I currently have a solution of using tags to create named caches derived from Type.FullName for each type of entity used as lookup data, but is there anything better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache used is the `MemoryCache`: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/shared/Z.EF.Plus.QueryCache.Shared/QueryCacheManager.cs#L41

> Would Entity Framework Plus check to see if the entities EF is about to materialize in memory already exist in the cache

Entities from both queries will be different. Even if they have the same id, the reference will not be the same. The reason behind it is that in the first query, you might have included related departments but not in the second. So we don't check at all if the entities are already in the cache or not.

> What is best practice to cache never-changing, or infrequently changed

It depends, if you only have 2000 employees, probably loading everything once and re-using the cache would be a very good solution. Filtering on the application side a small list doesn't hurt the performance:

```
var employees = myContext.LookupData.FromCache().Where(x=>x.Id < 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated.